# Terraform : Init

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have changed the version of the Terraform provider to get through an error and this has caused another one. I am using Azure Devops pipeline to build an Azure function.

And now I am receiving this error when the piepline does a Terraform Init. Other ones were done earlier in the pipeline and this has not caused this issue.

```
   Initializing the backend...
    ╷
    │ Error: Backend configuration changed
    │ 
    │ A change in the backend configuration has been detected, which may require
    │ migrating existing state.
    │ 
    │ If you wish to attempt automatic migration of the state, use "terraform
    │ init -migrate-state".
    │ If you wish to store the current configuration with no changes to the
    │ state, use "terraform init -reconfigure".
```

Comment: Receiving an error and then upgrading stuff without understanding the error and then getting another error should teach you something... That being said: have you run the commands listed here? Did you create a state backup? Did the backend configuration change?

Comment: Destroy everything and start again. Remember to not update stuff manually, only using TF.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by running `terraform init -reconfigure` and checking the version in the logs and amend as necessary.